# Export grid count figure as kml

Tags: python, matplotlib, kml, geopandas

I'm trying to export a grid count matplotlib figure as a kml export. The matplotlib figure is displaying so the grid count function is functioning.

Although, when opening the .kml export using google earth, the output isn't correctly displaying the grid count (screenshot attached).

Is it possible to show the grid count with a kml format?

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import shapely
import contextily as cx
import simplekml
from operator import itemgetter

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/Nuclear%20Waste%20Sites%20on%20American%20Campuses.csv')

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.lon, df.lat))
gdf.crs = "EPSG:4326"

fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.axis('off')

plt.axis('off')
border1 = plt.axis()

#if False:
#    plt.show()
#else:
#    pngName = 'Overlay.png'
#    fig.savefig(pngName, facecolor=fig.get_facecolor(), transparent=False)

# total area for the grid
#xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = gdf.total_bounds

bounds = gdf.geometry.apply(lambda x: x.bounds).tolist()
xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = min(bounds, key=itemgetter(0))[0], min(bounds, key=itemgetter(1))[1], max(bounds, key=itemgetter(2))[2], max(bounds, key=itemgetter(3))[3]

# how many cells across and down
n_cells = 10
cell_size = (xmax-xmin)/n_cells

# projection of the grid
#crs = "+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs"

# create the cells in a loop
grid_cells = []
for x0 in np.arange(xmin, xmax+cell_size, cell_size ):
    for y0 in np.arange(ymin, ymax+cell_size, cell_size):
        # bounds
        x1 = x0-cell_size
        y1 = y0+cell_size
        grid_cells.append(shapely.geometry.box(x0, y0, x1, y1))
        
cell = gpd.GeoDataFrame(grid_cells, columns = ['geometry'], crs = 'EPSG:4326')

merged = gpd.sjoin(gdf, cell, how='left', predicate='within')

# make a simple count variable that we can sum
merged['gridCount'] = 1

# Compute stats per grid cell -- aggregate fires to grid cells with dissolve
dissolve = merged.dissolve(by = 'index_right', aggfunc = 'count')

# put this into cell
cell.loc[dissolve.index, 'gridCount'] = dissolve['gridCount'].values

ax = cell.plot(column = 'gridCount', 
               figsize = (12, 8), 
               cmap = 'viridis_r', 
               vmax = 1000,
               alpha = 0.5,
               edgecolor = 'grey')
   
cx.add_basemap(ax, zoom = 8, crs = 'EPSG:4326')

pngName = 'Overlay.png'
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig(pngName, facecolor=fig.get_facecolor(), transparent=False)

bottomleft  = xmin,ymin
bottomright = xmax,ymin
topright    = xmax,ymax
topleft     = xmin,ymax

kml = simplekml.Kml()
ground = kml.newgroundoverlay(name='GroundOverlay')
ground.icon.href = pngName
ground.gxlatlonquad.coords =[bottomleft, bottomright, topright, topleft]
kml.save("GroundOverlay.kml")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your `df` don't have a column named `total_bounds`, how did `xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = df.total_bounds` work? And `gpd.sjoin` need two GeoDataFrames,  but the `df`is normal DataFrame.

Comment: Apologies, both have been rectified to incorporate `gdf` instead of `df`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you saved a blank picture and trying to use this picture for generating `.kml`. So the solution is to save the figure after the `cell.plot` :

```
ax = cell.plot(column = 'gridCount', 
               figsize = (12, 8), 
               cmap = 'viridis_r', 
               vmax = 1000,
               alpha = 0.5,
               edgecolor = 'grey')

pngName = 'Overlay.png'
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig(pngName, facecolor=fig.get_facecolor(), transparent=False)
```

Then you will get :

[image]

Update :

I have just copied the code you posted in the question, now I get the result as :

[image]

The first figure I have got is with code below :

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/Nuclear%20Waste%20Sites%20on%20American%20Campuses.csv')

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.lon, df.lat))
gdf.crs = "EPSG:4326"

fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.axis('off')

plt.axis('off')


# total area for the grid
xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = df.lon.min(), df.lat.min(), df.lon.max(), df.lat.max()

# how many cells across and down
n_cells = 30
cell_size = (xmax-xmin)/n_cells

# projection of the grid
#crs = "+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs"

# create the cells in a loop
grid_cells = []
for x0 in np.arange(xmin, xmax+cell_size, cell_size ):
    for y0 in np.arange(ymin, ymax+cell_size, cell_size):
        # bounds
        x1 = x0-cell_size
        y1 = y0+cell_size
        grid_cells.append(shapely.geometry.box(x0, y0, x1, y1))
        
cell = gpd.GeoDataFrame(grid_cells, columns = ['geometry'], crs = 'EPSG:4326')

merged = gpd.sjoin(gdf, cell, how='left', predicate='within')

# make a simple count variable that we can sum
merged['gridCount'] = 1

# Compute stats per grid cell -- aggregate fires to grid cells with dissolve
dissolve = merged.dissolve(by = 'index_right', aggfunc = 'count')

# put this into cell
cell.loc[dissolve.index, 'gridCount'] = dissolve['gridCount'].values

ax = cell.plot(column = 'gridCount', 
               figsize = (12, 8), 
               cmap = 'viridis_r', 
               vmax = 1000,
               alpha = 0.5,
               edgecolor = 'grey')


pngName = 'Overlay.png'
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig(pngName, facecolor=fig.get_facecolor(), transparent=False)
   
#cx.add_basemap(ax, zoom = 8, crs = 'EPSG:4326')

bottomleft  = xmin,ymin
bottomright = xmax,ymin
topright    = xmax,ymax
topleft     = xmin,ymax

kml = simplekml.Kml()
ground = kml.newgroundoverlay(name='GroundOverlay')
ground.icon.href = pngName
ground.gxlatlonquad.coords =[bottomleft, bottomright, topright, topleft]
kml.save("grid_count.kml")
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't return your output. Have I got the code right?

Comment: How did you get that output @ HMH1013? Could you put it in the whole answer?

Comment: @ Chopin I've made an update

Comment: Thanks. I mustn't have a driver installed or some separate issue. The output file size is only 500 bytes. I can only get the error output

Comment: I'm getting your first image returned. Is it possible to make the figure background transparent (not white)?